# How to create a 2-d List of String or Character type?

Tags: java, recursion, collections

So I was trying to solve this problem on leetcode -

https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/

Now I want to create a 2-d String-list in such a way that my "2" corresponds to a,b,c , "3" corresponds to d,e,f.... and so on in such a way that my 2-d list would look something like this - [[a,b,c],[d,e,f].....[w,x,y,z]] or we can say that each string character can be considered as a character in such a way that it would look like this -

a b c

d e f

.
.
.
.
.

w x y z

but I was not able to do so. I tried various methods such as -

1.

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
       str.add("abc");
       digitMap.add(0,str);
       str.set(0,"def");
       digitMap.add(1,str);
       str.set(0,"ghi");
       digitMap.add(2,str);
```

Usually when I want to pass any values in a 2-d list I first create a 1-d list and pass it's reference in the 2-d list and then empty the 1-d list but the values were getting overwritten as str acts a reference and any changes made to it will be visible in the digitMap due to which all the rows will have the same value which was last entered in str so this method failed.

2. I tried to create

```
List<List<String[]>> digitMap = new ArrayList<>();
```

so that each List contain a array of String [] type.

but was not able to store the values in which type of List  is of type String[].

I know we can use HashMap to store it in the (Key,Value) format but I would like to have a proper command on the List Interface.

I am really lost in the implementation part. Also it would be great help if someone would suggest me a link where I can learn in depth about Collections in java in layman terms.

Comment: you can directly use add, str.add("space_bar"), str.add("something else"),str.add(abc), now at index 2 you will have abc.
(or) str.add(abc) and for every digit x you need to do  (x-2) to get correct value

Comment: What are you trying to get `Map<Ineger,String>` ?  `Map<Ineger,List<String>` ? Note that a `List` is mutable so when you change it like `str.set(0,"def");` it will also change the list that was added before by `digitMap.add(0,str);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. See how it workes:

```
final char[][] L = {{},{},{'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'},{'j','k','l'},
{'m','n','o'},{'p','q','r','s'},{'t','u','v'},{'w','x','y','z'}};

public List<String> letterCombinations(String D) {
    int len = D.length();
    List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    if (len == 0) return ans;
    bfs(0, len, new StringBuilder(), ans, D);
    return ans;
}

public void bfs(int pos, int len, StringBuilder sb, List<String> ans, String D) {
    if (pos == len) ans.add(sb.toString());
    else {
        char[] letters = L[Character.getNumericValue(D.charAt(pos))];
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
            bfs(pos+1, len, new StringBuilder(sb).append(letters[i]), ans, D);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By what I understand, you wanted an output like this `[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],...,['w','x','y','z']]`. For this, the output list will ba a nested list. Loop through digits and add characters to a temporary list and add that list to the final output.

```
import java.util.*;
public class NestedList {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<List<String>> parent = new ArrayList<>();
        int inc = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            List<String> child = new ArrayList<>();
            child.add(Character.toString((char)(97 + (inc))));
            child.add(Character.toString((char)(97 + (inc + 1))));
            child.add(Character.toString((char)(97 + (inc + 2))));
            if (i == 7 || i == 9) {
                child.add(Character.toString((char)(97 + (inc + 3))));
                inc = inc + 4;
            } else {
                inc = inc + 3;
            }
            parent.add(child);
        }
        System.out.println(parent);
    }
}
```

Output;

```
[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [j, k, l], [m, n, o], [p, q, r, s], [t, u, v], [w, x, y, z]]
```

Let me know if it answers your query or if I misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: Shouldn't we not empty the child list after every iteration, like after 

parent.add(child);
child = null; or child = clear();

or is it that after every iteration a new local child list is being created? 
@Sana Mumtaz.

Comment: The variable `child` is declared and initialized inside the loop, hence its scope is limited to it only. So yes, for each loop a new variable is initialized.